# I have a little code in C which compiles, but gives wrong answer

Tags: c

I am very new to C programming. I want to give input for number and for a string. Then print it out. the program compiles but I get this output "You wrote 0". Any tips will be really valuable. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int number;
char cc[30];
scanf("Write number: %d\n", &number);
scanf("Write phrase: %s\n", cc);
printf("You wrote : %d %s",number,cc);  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The way you wrote it, scanf() is expecting your _input_ to include **Write number:** and a line-end.

Comment: Your `scanf` usage doesn't match the `scanf` specification. But I recommend the idea to factor out the required functions into a new function like `prompt_and_read_value` that has the semantic you expected.

Comment: Thank you . I understood the problem. I thought everything could be written in one line like Java println, but its not like that.

Answer (score 4):

For `scanf("Write number: %d\n", &number);` to success, you need to input something like "Write number: 42" and enter, I do not think this is what you want to do. You could replace that with this

```
printf("Write number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Another `scanf()` has the same problem and fix.

Comment: Thanks really. Now I understood the problem. I thought everything can be written in one line,  like Java, println. Now I understand the diff. between C and Java. Its not so alike.Thanks

Comment: @user3322635 Yeah, they are two different programming languages anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The format string you give to `scanf` is the format of the input it expects.

You want to use

```
printf("Write number: ");  // no trailing \n here
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't print using a scanf function. For this purpose you have to use a printf statement before a scanf statement.

```
printf("Write number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
printf("\nWrite phrase: ");
scanf("%s", cc);
printf("\nYou wrote : %d %s",number,cc);
```

Secondly, you should not use '\n' after the format specifier in the scanf statement.
The scanf statement uses '\n' i.e. newline, as the indicator that you have finished giving input to your function.
Even the following code will work:

```
scanf("%d", &number);
scanf("%s", cc);
```

And a better way to get this done is:

```
scanf("%d %s", &number, cc);
```

Comment: wow, full explanation. :) Thanks for your time to explain me all this. very useful